# Getting the state of JToggleButton

Tags: java, swing, listeners, jtogglebutton

Say I have a

```
JToggleButton but = new JToggleButton("OK") ;
```

Now I need the state of `but` when it is clicked. I mean I need to know if it's clicked or not.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can also use the itemListener's itemStateChanged method like follow:

```
JToggleButton jtb = new JToggleButton("Press Me");
jtb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
      if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        System.out.println("button is selected");
      } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        System.out.println("button is not selected");
      }
   }
});
```

and of you want to know the state of `jtb` latter on use `isSelected()` method

```
System.out.println(jtb.isSelected());
if(jtb.isSelected()){
    System.out.println("button is selected");
} else {
    System.out.println("button is not selected");
}
```

Comment: Since Java8 you can use lambda expression 
but.addItemListener((ItemEvent ev) -> { /* your code */ }

Answer (score 15):

To respond to clicks, add an ActionListener to the JToggleButton. To find it's state, just like a JRadioButton, call it's isSelected() method.

For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class ToggleTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JToggleButton toggleBtn = new JToggleButton("Toggle Me!");
      toggleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JToggleButton tBtn = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();
            if (tBtn.isSelected()) {
               System.out.println("button selected");
            } else {
               System.out.println("button not selected");
            }
         }
      });

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, toggleBtn);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that relies on event ordering. When you `actionPerformed` gets called before the internal button toggling listener, you get the [opposite result](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2011/06/15/swing-better-world-listeners).