# How can I set the toggled state of JToggleButton?

Tags: java, swing, border, jtogglebutton

I've added some JToggleButtons to a JPanel with a BoxLayout. The buttons have been placed in a ButtonGroup. Now I want to toggle some attributes for the currently selected button, only while it is selected. I'm looking for something like this:

```
buttonGroup.addSomeListener(new SomeListener() {
    @Override
    public void whenToggled() {
        /*set attributes for button*/
    }
});
```

Specifically I want selected buttons to display a `BevelBorder.LOWERED` as opposed to the

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
```

that the buttons in my JPanel have.

**EDIT**

this code doesn't print out "rollover" unless I simply change the type of `button` to `JButton` How can a JToggleButton listen for mouseOver in a changelistener?

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton();
  button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        ButtonModel mod = button.getModel();
        if (mod.isRollover()) {
            System.out.println("rollover");
        }
    }
  });
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.add(panel);
  panel.add(button);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, myself, I'd use an ItemListener. I'd also consider combining the beveled border with Toggle's inside border of its compound border as this will make the button fuller in size. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Foo {
   static CompoundBorder lowered; // = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED);
   static CompoundBorder raised; // = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();

      final ButtonGroup btnGrp = new ButtonGroup();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         JToggleButton toggle = new JToggleButton("Toggle " + (i + 1));
         if (lowered == null) {
            CompoundBorder toggleBorder = (CompoundBorder) toggle.getBorder();
            Border toggleInside = toggleBorder.getInsideBorder();
            lowered = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                  BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED),
                  toggleInside);
            raised = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                  BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED),
                  toggleInside);
         }
         toggle.setBorder(raised);
         btnGrp.add(toggle);
         panel.add(toggle);
         toggle.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent iEvt) {
               Border border = iEvt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ? lowered
                     : raised;
               ((JComponent) iEvt.getSource()).setBorder(border);
            }

         });
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }

}
```

Yep, I agree that this does not work:

```
     toggle.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
           ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) evt.getSource();

           // this doesn't work
           if (model.isRollover()) {
              System.out.println(model.getActionCommand() + " is rolled over");
           }

           // but this does
           if (model.isSelected()) {
              System.out.println(model.getActionCommand() + " is selected");
           }
        }
     });
```

Comment: So say I want to toggle effect for `mouseOver` aswell. Would you still go with ItemListener?

Comment: @user2651804: no, then you are correct, you'd need a ChangeListener added to the button's model.

Comment: In experimenting with `button.getModel().isRollover()` just now, a simple test shows that `JToggleButtons` don't fire changeEvents or don't listen to rollOver, whereas normal `JButton` does?

Comment: I made an edit to my question, asking how to use ChangeListener to listen for rollover of a JToggleButton. I hope you will take a look :)

Comment: @user2651804: yep, see edit. I'm not sure that JToggleButtons are wired to use the rollover property.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I asked my question too fast. I was looking for a `ChangeListener`. You want to apply the listener to the `ButtonModel` of your button.

```
button.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        if (model.isSelected()) {
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        } else {
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Myself, I'd use an Itemlistener.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer :
[Getting the state of JToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524536/getting-the-state-of-jtogglebutton)

This is the simplest way to do it :

```
JToggleButton jtb = new JToggleButton("Press Me");
jtb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
      if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        System.out.println("button is selected");
      } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        System.out.println("button is not selected");
      }
   }
});
```