# JToggleButton addItemListener seems to repeat the ItemListener forever

Tags: java, swing, itemlistener, gui-builder, jtogglebutton

I'm programming a `JToggleButton` to load to/discard from memory the configuration of an element (a telescope config), so I've added a `JComboBox` in a `JFrame` and near it the button to load the selected item. When the `JToggleButton` is selected, an hard disk icon is displayed, another icon if otherwise. I'm using the IntelliJ IDEA GUI editor for that. Of course, I've added an `ItemListener` (as suggested from the web) to that button:

```
    loadTelescopeButton.setSelected(true);
    System.out.println(loadTelescopeButton.isSelected());
    loadTelescopeButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            System.out.println("LAODACTION " + loadTelescopeButton.isSelected());
            try {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    String selected = telescopesList.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if ((selected != null) && (!selected.equals("")) && (ObjUtils.isAlphaNumeric(selected))) {
                        //...

                    } else {
                        showErrorMessage("Invalid id selected!");
                    }

                } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    if ((configurationActivity != null) && (configurationActivity.getManager() != null) &&
                            (configurationActivity.getTelescope() != null) && (configurationActivity.getTelescope().isConnected())) {
                        //...

                    } else {
                        //...
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Output: 
       `true` 
 -> When the window is displayed 
       `LAOD_ACTION false` 
 -> When I click the button

I've made some tests with some new toggle buttons and they gave me same error: the code inside `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {...}` is repeated forever, without stopping! In that piece of code there are no `for` and `while` loops! The result is a great number of message dialogs (only one dialog should be displayed), and if I focus another window in my desktop the screen behind the dialogs becomes black (the area of the parent window). I changed the listener to `ActionListener` and now everything is executed one time/click.

Why this error? I've copied that code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524627/6267019, as you can see.

Full code on GitHub [Here](https://github.com/SquareBoot/Telescope.Touch-server/blob/07405952a915f9a9fb76b8c6d09c3bf0ab1cdaea/src/squareboot/telescope/touch/MainActivity.java#L516-L565), I've highlighted the code for that toggle button. The same error happens with other `JToggleButton`s in my `MainActivity.java` file, and also when debugging IntelliJ lets me see that the code in the listener is repeated forever. After some thousand of dialogs Windows shows me a message and closes Java Platform Binary with an error.

EDIT:
The same problem in a new class:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class ErrorGUI extends JFrame {

     public ErrorGUI() throws HeadlessException {
         super("ciao");
         JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
         setContentPane(panel1);

         JToggleButton ciaoToggleButton = new JToggleButton("cajs");
         ciaoToggleButton.setSelected(true);
         ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
             System.out.println("caiooasfsdvn");
             try {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1, "skjngksfnb");

             } catch (Exception e2) {
                 e2.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
         panel1.add(ciaoToggleButton);

         pack();
         setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new ErrorGUI();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I know that fact and I'm sorry about that, but how can I post 1200 lines of code or the XML of the IntelliJ IDEA GUI builder? Which example can I provide, if the examples from the web run good?

Comment: That is the problem!! The examples work! If I create a new project, I add a  `main` and I write the code for a `JFrame` with a toggle button, it works!

Comment: My idea of the bug is that it is caused by an IntelliJ IDEA GUI builder internal error. Now I'm creating the same error in a new prj.

Comment: I've created the error in a new prj. With both GUI builder and "pure" Java, I can see the same problem. This time the dialog is displayed two times and not forever, but this is not what I need. I'll post the code in the post, just a moment.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, 1+ for the efforts. I'm not sure of the cause of the problem other than it has something to do with the JOptionPane somehow changing the state of the JToggleButton. This can be prevented by wrapping the JOptionPane call in a Runnable and queuing it on the Swing event queue via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you open a modal dialog, the opening method call will return only after the dialog has been closed. This is crucial for the dialogs that return an entered value or choice.

This implies that while the dialog is open, a new event handling loop has to be started to react on the input in the dialog.

So when you open a modal dialog from a listener, you are stopping the handling of the current event and start processing of subsequent events, which can disturb the handling of the current event significantly. Most notably, the button will suddenly loose the focus when the new dialog is opened.

The nested event handling can be easily demonstrated by changing the listener to

```
ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("entering");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1,
       e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED? "selected": "deselected");
    System.out.println("leaving");
});
```

which will print sequences of

```
entering
entering
leaving
leaving
```

showing how the contradicting event is generated while the processing of the old one hasn’t completed.

As said by others, you can fix this by opening the dialog *after* the completion of the even handling, like

```
ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("entering");
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1,
       e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED? "selected": "deselected"));
    System.out.println("leaving");
});
```

or you enforce a non-modal dialog:

```
ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("entering");
    JDialog d = new JOptionPane(
            e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED? "selected": "deselected",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE)
        .createDialog(panel1, UIManager.getString("OptionPane.messageDialogTitle"));
    d.setModal(false);
    d.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("leaving");
});
```

(in a real application you would either keep the dialog for later reuse or call `dispose` after use)

---

Unfortunately, the danger of opening modal dialogs (or doing anything else that creates a [secondary event loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#createSecondaryLoop--)) hasn’t been emphasized enough in the documentation. You can read everywhere that accessing Swing components from other threads can create inconsistencies, but starting new event handling loop while there are incompletely processed events can have a similar impact.

Comment: Note that in your original code, you are maxing this out by calling `setSelected(…);` on the event source from within the listener, which will, of course, trigger a new event delivery reporting the change right at this point, which is a recipe for infinite loops, even without dialogs.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. 1+. 10+ if I could

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! I will study this question later, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

I can't say that I understand why your code is misbehaving, but I agree that what you're seeing doesn't quite make sense, and is likely due to the JOptionPane call somehow affecting the JToggleButton's state change. One way to get around this is by wrapping the JOptionPane call in a Runnable and queuing it on the Swing event queue via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ErrorGUI extends JFrame {

    public ErrorGUI() throws HeadlessException {
        super("ciao");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panel1);

        JToggleButton ciaoToggleButton = new JToggleButton("cajs");
        ciaoToggleButton.setSelected(true);
        ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("caiooasfsdvn");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1, "skjngksfnb");
            });
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1, "skjngksfnb");

        });
        panel1.add(ciaoToggleButton);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ErrorGUI();
        });

    }
}
```

An interesting variation:

```
ciaoToggleButton.setSelected(true);
System.out.println("0:" + ciaoToggleButton.isSelected());
ciaoToggleButton.addItemListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("1: " + ciaoToggleButton.isSelected());
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1, "skjngksfnb");
    }
    System.out.println("2: " + ciaoToggleButton.isSelected());

});
```

prints out:

```
0:true
1: false
2: false
1: true
1: false
2: false
2: false
1: true
1: false
2: false
2: false
```

Comment: Thanks, but here's another strange thing: I've written `loadTelescopeButton.setSelected(true);
        System.out.println(loadTelescopeButton.isSelected());
        loadTelescopeButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("LAOD_ACTION " + loadTelescopeButton.isSelected()); //... other code` in the constructor. In the console I see `LAOD_ACTION false` when I click the button!

Comment: @SquareBoot: please edit your question. Code in comments is difficult to read unless it's very small.

Comment: Really thanks for the answer! So, it seems to be a Java bug, in my opinion. I've been spending so much time on the toggle button that I'm going to make a custom `JComponent`

Comment: @SquareBoot: If I have time later, I am going to have to look at the source code to see what's going on, but not now, after only 4 hours sleep.

Comment: This is not related to `JOptionPane`; any modal dialog will trigger the same behavior.