# Swing Invoke Later Events vs Modal Dialogs

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog

I created a Modal Dialog by extending JDialog. As soon as setVisible(true) gets called code flow gets stuck at that point until the dialog gets dispose (as per expectation).

However i do not know/understand what happens to all the events already scheduled by using `SwingUtilites.invokeLater()`, does these events also get hold up until modal dialog closes or they are independent and do get executed when the modal dialog is still open ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will be blocking the ongoing processing of the current event at that point, but a secondary event loop will process the subsequent events. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511714/2711488) which explains it by discussing a problem caused by this behavior.

Comment: @Holger secondary event loop starts working on the next event from same event queue until primary finishes with Modal Dialog ?

Comment: The primary loop doesn’t make progress as long as it is blocked in `setVisible(true)`. The dialog will be closed as a reaction of an event processed by the secondary loop (window close button, escape key, or whatever).

Comment: Thanks @Holger, Please put it as an answer and i shall accept it :)